# Find Number of Days in one year using DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

I want to use DateTime to find the number of Saturdays and Sundays between the start of the input year and End of the input year using C# windows form.

Condition: I cannot use any loops to run through the start to the end of the year. I need to find a way to hard calculate the number of Saturdays and Sundays in one year.

The following is a code I wrote for the same goal using for loop for your reference:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int inputYear = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
            DateTime begginingOfYear = new DateTime(inputYear, 01, 01);
            DateTime endOfYear = new DateTime(inputYear + 1, 01, 01);


            int satIndex = 0;
            int sunIndex = 0;

            for (DateTime date = begginingOfYear; date <= endOfYear; date = date.AddDays(1))
            {
                if (date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
                {
                    sunIndex++;
                }
                else if (date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
                {
                    satIndex++;
                }
            }

            MessageBox.Show($"Saturdays{Convert.ToString(satIndex)}days , Sundays{Convert.ToString(sunIndex)}days");
```

Comment: Please do not add random tags to your question. This question has nothing to do with using the Windows Forms Designer in Visual Studio (the GUI tool for designing Windows Forms UI), nor does it have anything to do with Windows Forms itself (so if that's the tag you were going for, that's not relevant either).

Comment: As for your question: today is Sunday. If I ask you how many Saturdays and Sundays there are between today and March 6th 2023, a Monday, you should be able to calculate this fairly trivially by working out the number of days between these two dates, whether the start or end dates are weekend days, and simple arithmetic. You can do something like `TimeSpan timeBetweenDates = d2 - d1; int days = (int)timeBetweenDates.TotalDays;` and the `.DayOfWeek` property.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [number of Saturdays and Sundays of a specific year and month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190482/number-of-saturdays-and-sundays-of-a-specific-year-and-month)

Answer (score 1):

A year has `52` weeks plus `1` or `2` extra days, that's why given a year `y`

```
// int.TryParse can be a safier approach
int y = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
```

we can use a simple condition:

```
int satIndex = new DateTime(y, 1, 1).DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday ||
               new DateTime(y, 1, 1).DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday && 
                   DateTime.IsLeapYear(y)
  ? 53
  : 52;

int sunIndex = new DateTime(y, 1, 1).DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday ||
               new DateTime(y, 1, 1).DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday &&
                   DateTime.IsLeapYear(y)
  ? 53
  : 52;
```